# Redirect Angular2 http requests through proxy

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm creating Angular2 application using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) bootstrapper and use `webpack-dev-server` for debugging purposes.

For some kinds of http request I want to redirect them to another backend using webpack-dev-server [proxy support](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy).

For this reason I've created `proxy.conf.json` file:

```
{
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4201",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And map angular cli to use this config file:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

After starting console message notifies me that proxy created successfully:

> NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200
>
> Proxy created: /api/**  ->  http://localhost:4201

But all request from `http://localhost:4200/api/users` always returns with 404 status code. I tried many examples of mapping urls but nothing helps:

```
"/api/users" -> "http://localhost:4201/users"
"/api/" -> "http://localhost:4201/"
```

Data from my proxied server are requesting successfully. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you created file called proxy.config.json but you run ng serve with proxy.conf.json. I renamed the file to proxy.conf.json and pointed to http://google.com instead of http://localhost:4201 and it works for me. So config is fine.

Comment: Just misspelling. I've rectified it. But still not work (

Comment: try to change localhost:4201 to google.com in your config

Comment: Changed to google.com and still no luck. I'm receiving 404 in google also. How to inspect in angular-cli generated project proxy log? Strange about 404

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found solution. I've created simple express server to log all requests transferred from proxy server to inspect how mapping works. And I found out that I had wrong understanding about mapping.

Instead of strict mapping defined in config file:

```
/api/users => http://localhost:4201/users
```

webpack proxy server map using next rule:

```
/api/users => http://localhost:4201/users/api/users
```

So solution here is to add `pathRewrite` parameter to exclude prefix

```
{
  "/api/users": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4201",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explain us the way you fixed your issue ! You saved my day, I was exactly in the same case! Works perfectly!

Comment: @VadimB hi i am having similar kind of problem after doing these fix also its showing net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Maybe some issues with target endpoint. Could you share your config?