# Angular-cli: issues setting up the proxy to handle complex requests going to another domain

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am busy with a web app that needs to make http requests to a server on my local network.  i'm using Angular-cli to build/run my project.  When makeing any complex requests i'm running into CORS issues  and trying to use the angular-cli proxy to handle those complex requests...  I set it up exactly as it's done on the angular-cli github page but it doesn't seem to work.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

my code:

```
proxy.conf.json:

{
"/api":{
"target":"http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/",
"secure":false
}
}
```

from package.json:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

a function with a complex request that's supposed to go to the proxy:

```
postStockTake(stockTakeModel: StockTakeModel) : Observable<Response> {    
  return this.http.post("/api" + "/StockTake/AddToStockTake", JSON.stringify(stockTakeModel), {headers: this.headers})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
  }
```

I then run the app with npm start instead of ng serve...  When it starts to build I see the following in my command prompt console:

```
> barcode-checker@0.0.0 start C:\Users\User1\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker
> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

And in my chrome dev tools console I see:

```
zone.js:1725
POST
http://localhost:4200/api/StockTake/AddToStockTake
405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

So it's clearly still trying to post to localhost even though I added the local server's IP address in the target value of the proxy.conf file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had similar problem before and I found out that proxy map path not as was expected.

When I have config:

```
{
  "/api":{
  "target":"http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/",
  "secure":false
}
```

I expect all requests to `api/<sub-path>` path will be mapped to `http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/<sub-path>`, but it's incorrect.

Your virtual path `api/<sub-path>` will be mapped to:

```
http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/api/<sub-path>
```

So I got incorrect url I and my server throwing similar error. Solution for was to remove incorrect `api` subpath from my destination url using next configuration option

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

I had similar question but did not receive answer so found solution for my problem themself.

[Redirect Angular2 http requests through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488769/redirect-angular2-http-requests-through-proxy)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @VadimB that fixed it!:)

Comment: Cool, glad to help you :)

Comment: Thanks! you saved my day! Also Juri Strumpflohner explains it very well in a video on his blog: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: @VadimB Any idea to use proxy in Prod build?