# Angular is not using the api server

Tags: angular

I just started with a Angular 4 & Spring Boot web application. I'm trying to call a REST path:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Make the HTTP request:
  this.http.get('/greeting').subscribe(data => {
    // Read the result field from the JSON response.
    this.results = data['results'];
  });
}
```

But the resulting URL is `GET http://localhost:4200/greeting 404 (Not Found)`. I've researched this topic and a lot of advice was to add a proxy file for NPM so it changes the routes.

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

And the `proxy.conf.json` file:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

When I run npm run start I get the following message:

> movie-seat@0.0.0 start
>       C:\Users\alucardu\Documents\projects\movieseat\frontend\src\main\frontend> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
>
> Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

So the proxy file is loaded but it has no effect. Am I using outdated information or just doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you're exactly doing here, but can't you just give the `get` call a full URL  ?

Comment: What is the resulting URL now?

Comment: @marouane kadiri You are wrong. If you want to call local api your server probably runs on another port so you need proxy. It will also let you avoid problems with same-origin-policy that you would have using full URL

Comment: @Arkej as stated in the question. The resulting url is `http://localhost:4200/greeting` so it's doing the request from the NPM server.

Comment: try to change `/api` to `/*` in your `proxy.conf.json`

Comment: @Arkej NPM doesn't seem to like `Error: [HPM] Invalid context. Expecting something like: "/api" or ["/api", "/ajax"]`

Comment: @Arkej Thanks for clarification

Comment: try to change `/api` to `/api/*` in your proxy.conf.json, then change `/greeting` to `api/greeting` in your HTTP request

Comment: @PeterBoomsma do you get response from `http://localhost:8080/api/greeting` ?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this answer > [Redirect Angular2 http requests through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488769/redirect-angular2-http-requests-through-proxy). And adding this line:

```
"pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
```

To the proxy.conf.json file fixed my problem.

```
{
    "/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8090",
        "secure": false,
        "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
    }
}
```

I can now call a function like so:

```
getGreeting() {
  this.http.get('/greeting').subscribe(data => {
    // Read the result field from the JSON response.
    this.results = data['results'];
  });
}
```

And it calls the `http://localhost:4200/greeting` with success and it returns the correct headers. It also seems to "fix" the CORS problem. I don't need to specify any CORS code in my spring-boot backend.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wrong path in your `init`

Should be like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Make the HTTP request:
  this.http.get('./api/greeting').subscribe(data => {
    // Read the result field from the JSON response.
    this.results = data['results'];
  });
}
```

And add `*` in your proxy.config

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterBoomsma did you just try that path in your browser? it won't work like that. Did you try it in your project? I have exact setup in my project and it works without any issue

Comment: I checked around some more and found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488769/redirect-angular2-http-requests-through-proxy. Adding `"pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}`  to the proxy conf file worked. And I don't need to add /api to the get url.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma glad that you sorted it. Although I don't think pathRewrite is problem solver. I think it is solved because you changed `"/api/*"` to `/`

Comment: It didn't really mather what I renamed that path to. /api / api/*.

Comment: I meant if you removed `api` completely

Answer (score -1):

I suggest your Spring Boot Application is running on Port 8080.
Just write the total URL into the GET-Request:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/greeting').subscribe(data => {
```

If you want change the host for production and test environment, then exclude the host as a constant in the existing environment file and import it. Then you could do this:

```
this.http.get( PROD + '/greeting').subscribe
```